# Looping through character data and items from MySQL DB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, actionscript-3

I have the following code:

```
include "config.php";
error_reporting(0);

$idSuccess = 0;

if(isset($_POST['userName']))
{

    $usr = $_POST['userName'];
    $pwd = $_POST['userPwd'];
    $sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM dr_users where dr_user_name='$usr' AND dr_user_pwd='$pwd' LIMIT 1";
    $q = mysql_query($sqlQ);

    if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)
    {

        $userO = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
        $userData = array('userID' => $userO['dr_user_id'], 'userName' => $userO['dr_user_name'], 'userPwd' => $userO['dr_user_pwd'], 'userEml' => $userO['dr_user_email'], 'privLvl' => $userO['dr_user_priv_level']);
        $idSuccess = 1;
        $uID = $userO['dr_user_id'];
        $charQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dr_chars WHERE dr_user_id='$uID'");

        while($char = mysql_fetch_array($charQ))
        {

            $chars[] = $char;
            $charID = $char['dr_char_id'];
            $itemQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dr_items WHERE dr_char_id='$charID'");

            while($item = mysql_fetch_array($itemQ))
            {

                $itemData[] = array('itemID' => $item['dr_item_id'], 'itemName' => $item['dr_item_name'], 'itemDesc' => $item['dr_item_desc'], 'itemType' => $item['dr_item_type'], 'itemCost' => $item['dr_item_cost'], 'itemCurType' => $item['dr_item_cur_type'], 'itemAtk' => $item['dr_item_stat_atk'], 'itemDef' => $item['dr_item_stat_def'], 'itemEnd' => $item['dr_item_stat_end'], 'itemLuck' => $item['dr_item_stat_luck'], 'itemFileURL' => $item['dr_item_file_url'], 'itemStaff' => $item['dr_item_staff'], 'itemEquipped' => $item['dr_char_eqp'], 'spX' => $item['dr_static_pos_x'], 'spY' => $item['dr_static_pos_y']);                

            }

            $charData[] = array('charID' => $char['dr_char_id'], 'charName' => $char['dr_char_name'], 'charRace' => $char['dr_char_race'], 'charLvl' => $char['dr_char_lvl'], 'charItems' => $itemData);

        }

        $resData = array('idSuccess' => $idSuccess, 'user' => $userData, 'chars' => $charData);

    } else {


    $resData = array('idSuccess' => $idSuccess);

    }

    echo json_encode($resData);

}

?>
```

I have successfully loaded character data from the table 'dr_chars' in my database. I'm trying to load the corresponding item data from the retrieved character ID and push it into the $charData array. So I can then easily encode & output it in a JSON format.

If my question isn't clear just ask and I'll try to explain the situation better. The JSON data is being outputted into flash for dynamic use.

I managed to fix this final code as follows:

```
<?php

include "config.php";
error_reporting(0);

$idSuccess = 0;

if(isset($_POST['userName']))
{

    $usr = $_POST['userName'];
    $pwd = $_POST['userPwd'];
    $sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM dr_users where dr_user_name='$usr' AND dr_user_pwd='$pwd' LIMIT 1";
    $q = mysql_query($sqlQ);

    if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)
    {

        $userO = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
        $userData = array('userID' => $userO['dr_user_id'], 'userName' => $userO['dr_user_name'], 'userPwd' => $userO['dr_user_pwd'], 'userEml' => $userO['dr_user_email'], 'privLvl' => $userO['dr_user_priv_level']);
        $idSuccess = 1;
        $uID = $userO['dr_user_id'];
        $charQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dr_chars WHERE dr_user_id='$uID'");
        $chars = array();

        while($char = mysql_fetch_array($charQ))
        {


            $charID = $char['dr_char_id'];
            $itemQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dr_items WHERE dr_char_id='$charID'");
            $items = array();

            while($item = mysql_fetch_array($itemQ))
            {

                $items[] = array('itemID' => $item['dr_item_id'], 'itemName' => $item['dr_item_name'], 'itemDesc' => $item['dr_item_desc'], 'itemType' => $item['dr_item_type'], 'itemCost' => $item['dr_item_cost'], 'itemCurType' => $item['dr_item_cur_type'], 'itemAtk' => $item['dr_item_stat_atk'], 'itemDef' => $item['dr_item_stat_def'], 'itemEnd' => $item['dr_item_stat_end'], 'itemLuck' => $item['dr_item_stat_luck'], 'itemFileURL' => $item['dr_item_file_url'], 'itemStaff' => $item['dr_item_staff'], 'itemEquipped' => $item['dr_char_eqp'], 'spX' => $item['dr_static_pos_x'], 'spY' => $item['dr_static_pos_y']);

            }

            $chars[] = array('charID' => $char['dr_char_id'], 'charName' => $char['dr_char_name'], 'charRace' => $char['dr_char_race'], 'charLvl' => $char['dr_char_lvl'], 'charItems' => $items);

        }

        $resData = array('idSuccess' => $idSuccess, 'user' => $userData, 'chars' => $chars);

    } else {


    $resData = array('idSuccess' => $idSuccess);

    }

    echo json_encode($resData);

}

?>
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Any error messages?

Comment: No error messages it's just outputting incorrectly.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6z6s2PHx